# Carriage often stalls in my printer HP - Deskject 4185

Tags: printer, printing

of late, the carriage often stalls in my printer. The printer model is **HP-Deskjet-4185**.

The stalling does not happen when I initiate printing. The typical series of incidents leading to stalling of printer carriage is as follows -

1. Switch on Computer alone (Windows
   XP)
2. Open PDF document which I want to
   print
3. Turn on printer
4. Feed paper to the printer
5. Give print command on Acrobat Reader

Printing works fine. The two pages of the PDF document are printed successfully. And, then printer carriage stalls.

Any particular reason as to why it stalls?

How can I fix it? Any suggestions would greatly help!

**NOTE**: I feed page by page rather than putting all papers together as sometimes the printer takes more than 1 paper as input. So, when I am printing 2 pages, I insert one page...wait for it to complete printing. Printer comes up with the message that it has run out of paper, I then feed the other paper. And, this is how I have been doing it for ages and it has worked fine so far.

Comment: It's probably just old.

Comment: Its just 2.5 years old. Is the lifetime of printers only 2 years?

Comment: My HP Officejet D135 carriage stalled because of accumulated waste ink in the head parking station. The fix was dis-assembly and clean out of that area.

Comment: @W_Whalley: Head parking station? Hmm. I will take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @W_Whalley: Can you please make your comment as an answer so that I can accept that as an answer. I did exactly what you suggested and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Kanini: I've done that. Thanks for the accept. Re: paper feeding problem. You may have different results if you change to another paper supplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My HP Officejet D135 carriage stalled because of accumulated waste ink in the head parking station. The fix was dis-assembly and clean out of that area.